# Django - safe to store debugging data in request.META

Tags: python, django, exception, logging

As we know, if there is an error with your django application and you have `debug=True`, then you will see something like

[image]

Although I am not sure, I assume that if `debug=False`, we would still have access to this same thing except django would email this html file to us instead.

Following this assumption (someone please confirm), I have been tasked with adding another section to this exception template (USER, GET, POST, FILES, ETC [NEW CUSTOM SECTION HERE]).

However, since I dont know how to do that, I thought an easier way would just to set a bunch of custom key values into `request.META`

Would it be safe to do so? Like say an API secret key or something? So when something goes wrong, I would see it in the `META` of the formatted log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DEBUG = False" does not display the above screen.

see also

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#debug
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django

Comment: I know that `debug=False` will not display the above screen - it will send it to my email, right?

Answer (score 1):

adding an exception is very easy for example:

```
class IamHandsome(Exception):
    """ the user is too handsome """
    pass
```

call it inside your logic

```
# ...
if userIsTooHansome():
   raise IamHandsome
```

then you only need to use try catch block

```
try:
   # calling some function with exception logic
   # ...
except IamHandsome as e:
   pass
```

Putting it in meta (especially secret) is not advisable. if you can see it, then anybody else can do it too.

If you want to see it directly you can use [log settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) to put it as log file then access it (assuming you are using *nix)

```
tail -f log_location/django_log_file.log
```